# How to access etcd in docker

Tags: docker, etcd

I create a container by

```
docker run  -d --name etcd \
-v /usr/share/ca-certificates/:/etc/ssl/certs \ 
quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.0.4 /usr/local/bin/etcd -advertise-client-urls \ 
http://0.0.0.0:2379 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379
```

And use

```
 docker exec 40cc9457f132 ifconfig
```

to get its IP "172.17.0.2"

And then I use local etcdctl to get data,

```
 etcdctl --endpoint=http://172.17.0.2:2379 get /testdir/testkey1
```

but fail with:

```
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:2379: getsockopt: connection refused
```

What should I do?

PS:
To make sure the data is actually stored on the container, I stoped local etcd first.

```
systemctl stop etcd
```

If I don't do that, I could get the data, but it's not the same with the result of

```
docker exec 40cc9457f132 etcdctl get /testdir/testkey1
```

"40cc9457f132 " is the container id.

Answer (score 1):

OK， I fix it. It's the problem of version.
My local etcd is v2.2.4 (installed by `apt install`), and the etcd image version is v3.0.4.

I update both of them to v3.3.5 and set $ETCDCTL_API=3. 
Now it seems all right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that same port use both localhost and docker container.
please assign another port for container. example 2379->2380

```
etcdctl --endpoint=http://localhost:2379 -> localhost
etcdctl --endpoint=http://localhost:2380 -> docker container
```

Comment: Thanks. But I think their IP is different. localhost is `http://127.0.0.1:2379` , and docker container is `http://172.17.0.2:2379`.   Am i wrong?

Comment: yep, docker container would use another port. so you connect http://localhost:xxxx.
you can't connect to http://172.17.0.2:2379 on other computer.
becase of, docker ip (172.17.0.2) is nat ip.

Comment: in yml file, put a port mapping.
      ports:
       - "2380:2379" #Port etcd